# Excel Pivot Table calculated field question - formulas based on pivot table totals?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm having difficult adding a calculated field into my pivot table. It seems like it should be simple but perhaps I am dreaming :). Perhaps this is just a limitation of pivot tables, but I was hoping to create a calculated % field using totals in the pivot table. See my screenshot link - I hope this clarifies what I am seeking.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSIEU.png

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change how the values are displayed to be a percentage of row total. Right click on the data to open the Value Field Settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to see both the numbers and the percentages, you can add the EID column to the data a 2nd time. Once to show the counts, and the other to show the counts as percentages of row total:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm using Excel Japanese version now so don't know what is that menu in English,
but let try click on pivot table, on Analyst tab
select something like field/item/set
then select menu with (F)
in new window name your new field and set caculate way = yes / all (depend on what field name you have)
finally format this field as %